# How do interrupts work with usb splitters?

Tags: cpu, interrupt, interrupt-handling

From what I understand, each input port (which I presume means USB/SATA/PCIe etc.) has it's own interrupt line to the CPU which, when called, triggers off some kind of handler assosiated with that line.

If I have a keyboard with a USB socket on it and I plug in a mouse, how does the CPU distinguish between them given they're coming through the same input port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not quite correct.   A given device will likely have one or more interrupts associated with it.  That notion of a device is a *controller* directly connected to the cpu, not a socket or port.  In the USB example, your machine may have as many USB controllers as ports; but more likely has a built-in USB hub, which multiplexes a single controller, and presents multiple ports to the user.

The purpose of the interrupt is to tell the CPU that the device controller needs some attention, is available for more output or has input available for use.  If too many devices share an interrupt, the CPU has to search for which one desires attention.   This search increases the latency of servicing the device, thus should be minimized.  So the number of interrupts per device controller is a function of optimizing the search for the appropriate handler, vs the complexity of implementing the device (or *controller* driver).

At this level of device interaction the distinction between a keyboard & mouse is irrelevant -- it is a device generating and accepting data from a controller.  In the USB case, a *class* driver is layered on top of the *controller* driver, which interprets the data in the context of the attached device.  Typically when the controller is reset, or a device is plugged in or out, a dispatcher determines, based on values in a common protocol, type type of device, and thus appropriate class driver to configure for it.

So, the concept of a *device driver* typically has multiple layers: the interaction of the hardware being at the lower or *controller* level; the protocol associated with the semantics of the device, at the upper or *class* level.

This schematic shows the hardware connections between CPU and USB devices, such as keyboards, that you plug into a USB port.

```
keyboard---+ USB         USB   +---intr signal-----+ CPU
mouse------+ hub +-----+ contr                        |
sdcard-----+             oller +---data/addr bus+-----+---+ RAM
```

Notice many devices (left) connect,via ports, to one USB hub, which is then attached to a USB controller.  The USB controller is directly connected to the CPU interrupt controller, and shares a connection to RAM with the CPU.
The corresponding software schematic is:

```
Input ======= keyboard class driver ====* USB
              mouse class driver =======* device
filesystem == sdcard class driver ======* driver
```

On the left Input and filesystem are *presentation layer*-like software frameworks that present the expected end user experience -- press a key, the corresponding letter appears somewhere; click on file and it opens.

These levels provide this by interacting with *class drivers* which convert whatever underlying device information into an standard form which the presentation layer can understand.

Each *class driver* speaks to a device driver which interacts with the physical controller.  In USB, this has two main components - interrupts which are demands from the USB controller for the CPU to do *something*, and data packets which are stored in RAM under the drivers control.

The driver interprets enough of these packets to know which class driver to pass them onto.

Questions:
1) I mean a *device controller*.

2) The dispatcher is usually part of the kernel which works in concert with interrupt controller hardware to quickly resolve the cause of the interrupt.  The CPU architecture defines how an interrupt changes the execution flow in a CPU.  If multiple *device controllers* share an interrupt, the interrupt handler needs to determine which controller triggered the interrupt.   Thankfully there is hardware to help with this.

3) See diagram above.

Comment: Sorry for the late response to this!

I’m afraid I’m still confused…

When you say “a give device” - do you mean an individual peripheral? (e.g. a keyboard) or one of the device controllers you mention?

And following on, when you say there are “multiple interrupts associated with a given device” - do you mean an individual peripheral (e.g. a keyboard) has multiple interrupt lines attached to it?

Are controllers part of the hardware, i.e  the motherboard (or somewhere), or software as opposed to being part of the peripheral itself?

Comment: Is a dispatcher part of a device controller or is that also hardware/software on the motherboard? How is this triggered off?
 
When you say the CPU has to “search” for the device that requires attention, what is it searching? Surely it knows where the interrupt came from? Is it just asking the device driver which port it came from?

Comment: I’m afraid I’m not really familiar with the flow of these components at all - would you be able to elaborate it for me? I assume it’s something like the following:

Peripheral sends something to the Device Controller which sends it to the Class Controller which interprets it as data/interrupt and either interrupts the CPU or sends relevant data to some bus so the CPU can access it.

Conversely, I assume the CPU asks a peripheral for data by going to the class/device controller (after searching?) an having it tell the peripheral in question to output some data.